# Нужна помощь с составлении регулярного выражения

Tags: python, re

Мне нужно сделать проверку, что введенные пользователем данные в таком формате:

Иванов Иван Иванович, 1665645, https://t.me/ivan

Но у меня как то не получается, так как пока еще слаб в регулярках, может кто помочь ?

Comment: Пример данных добавляйте текстом

Comment: Так если пользоватесь ввел все по шаблону, то это отправляется на почту, я хочу избежать лишнего флуда

Comment: Тут не лечат по фотографиям. Если кто-то будет для вас писать регулярку, то у него должны быть данные, на которых её можно будет проверить.

Comment: Так на фото и есть шаблон, по которому текст должен проверяться: ФИО, индекс, телеграм, если введеный пользователем текст этому соответсвует, то код идет дальше

Comment: Ну то есть регулярку нужно будет проверять по фотографии? Или кто-то за вас должен будет с фотографии текст набить, чтобы регулярку проверить, что она работает? Толково.

Comment: Я не сразу понял, что ты имел ввиду, извиняюсь. Добавил текст

Answer (score 2):

```
[А-Яа-я]+\s+[А-Яа-я]+\s+[А-Яа-я]+,([ ]*)+([0-9]{7})+,([ ]*)+(http|https):\/\/t.me\/(([^_])([A-Za-z]{4,32})([^_]))
```

Разбор:

- `[А-Яа-я]+\s` - 1-3 слово. от А/а до Я/я. После слова 1 и более пробел
- `+,([ ]*)+([0-9]{7})+,([ ]*)+` - 4 слово. После 3 слова 0 и более пробелов, комбинация из символов от 0 до 9. Размер ровно 7 символов
- `+,([ ]*)+(http|https):\/\/t.me\/` - 5 слово (ссылка). По аналогии, проверка на 0 и более пробелов, проверка введён http или https, проверка "//t.me/", проверка от A/a до Z/z до бесконечности
- `(([^_])([A-Za-z]{4,32})([^_]))` - имя пользователя. Длина от 5 до 32. Не может начинаться на _ и заканчиваться на _

Тестировал через сайт https://regexr.com/

Не очень точно знаю регулярку, поэтому не смог вспомнить, как пробелы нормально оформить без `+([ ]{1,})+`. Если есть предложения, пишите в комментариях - поправлю.

Тестируемые слова:

- Иванов Иван Иванович, 1665645, https://t.me/ivanqq
- Пушкин Сашок Сергеевич, 951723, https://t.me/qwe
- Иванов Иван Иванович, 1665645, https://t.me/ivanq
- Иванов Иван Иванович, 1665645, https://t.me/_ivanq
- Иванов Иван Иванович, 1665645, https://t.me/ivanq_____
- Иванов Иван Иванович, 1665245, https://t.me/ivn

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В телеграмме ссылка на пользователя, должна минимум содержать 5 символов, максимум - 32. Также имя пользователя не может начинаться и заканчиваться с  `_`

Comment: @SelectionForCollection Поправил

Comment: Я не очень понимаю, что вот это значит: '([ ]\S*)+' , почему не просто '/s+' ?

Comment: `Петров-Водкин` на вас обидится.

Comment: @Vladimir Заменил `([ ]\S*)+` на `([ ]?)`, т.к. пробел после запятой может быть, а может не быть. Красивой конструкции для этого не нашёл, поэтому решил оставить так

Comment: ну так * и служит же для того, что может быть от нуля и более вхождений, а + от 1 и более